# How to get the value without encoding in vb.net watch?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

In vb.net in debugging you can watch a variable and right click.

There are options between copy and copy value.

There is little differences. I basically got this

> "[" & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""id"": 22812485751," & vbCrLf & "    ""currencyPair"": ""ORME/BTC""," & vbCrLf & "    ""goodUntilTime"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""type"": ""LIMIT_SELL""," & vbCrLf & "    ""orderStatus"": ""EXECUTED""," & vbCrLf & "    ""issueTime"": 1539721209920," & vbCrLf & "    ""price"": 2.726E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""quantity"": 1733.83246147," & vbCrLf & "    ""remainingQuantity"": 0.0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionByTrade"": 8.508E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusByTrade"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusRate"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionRate"": 0.0018," & vbCrLf & "    ""lastModificationTime"": 1539727280096" & vbCrLf & "  }," & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""id"": 19661583751," & vbCrLf & "    ""currencyPair"": ""ORME/ETH""," & vbCrLf & "    ""goodUntilTime"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""type"": ""LIMIT_BUY""," & vbCrLf & "    ""orderStatus"": ""EXECUTED""," & vbCrLf & "    ""issueTime"": 1537113087231," & vbCrLf & "    ""price"": 0.00110001," & vbCrLf & "    ""quantity"": 1733.83246562," & vbCrLf & "    ""remainingQuantity"": 0.0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionByTrade"": 0.003433," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusByTrade"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusRate"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionRate"": 0.0018," & vbCrLf & "    ""lastModificationTime"": 1538092923124" & vbCrLf & "  }," & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""id"": 19669018551," & vbCrLf & "    ""currencyPair"": ""ORME/BTC""," & vbCrLf & "    ""goodUntilTime"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""type"": ""LIMIT_SELL""," & vbCrLf & "    ""orderStatus"": ""EXECUTED""," & vbCrLf & "    ""issueTime"": 1537118640003," & vbCrLf & "    ""price"": 4.302E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""quantity"": 1140.08057366," & vbCrLf & "    ""remainingQuantity"": 0.0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionByTrade"": 8.829E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusByTrade"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusRate"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionRate"": 0.0018," & vbCrLf & "    ""lastModificationTime"": 1537119048771" & vbCrLf & "  }," & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""id"": 19666104251," & vbCrLf & "    ""currencyPair"": ""ORME/BTC""," & vbCrLf & "    ""goodUntilTime"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""type"": ""LIMIT_SELL""," & vbCrLf & "    ""orderStatus"": ""PARTIALLY_FILLED_AND_CANCELLED""," & vbCrLf & "    ""issueTime"": 1537116476248," & vbCrLf & "    ""price"": 4.25E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""quantity"": 7487.1," & vbCrLf & "    ""remainingQuantity"": 1140.08057366," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionByTrade"": 0.00048563," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusByTrade"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusRate"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionRate"": 0.0018," & vbCrLf & "    ""lastModificationTime"": 1537116507585" & vbCrLf & "  }," & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""id"": 19661490851," & vbCrLf & "    ""currencyPair"": ""ETH/BTC""," & vbCrLf & "    ""goodUntilTime"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""type"": ""LIMIT_BUY""," & vbCrLf & "    ""orderStatus"": ""EXECUTED""," & vbCrLf & "    ""issueTime"": 1537113025233," & vbCrLf & "    ""price"": 0.03357901," & vbCrLf & "    ""quantity"": 1.91066607," & vbCrLf & "    ""remainingQuantity"": 0.0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionByTrade"": 0.00011548," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusByTrade"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusRate"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionRate"": 0.0018," & vbCrLf & "    ""lastModificationTime"": 1537113028429" & vbCrLf & "  }," & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""id"": 17637942051," & vbCrLf & "    ""currencyPair"": ""ORME/BTC""," & vbCrLf & "    ""goodUntilTime"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""type"": ""LIMIT_SELL""," & vbCrLf & "    ""orderStatus"": ""EXECUTED""," & vbCrLf & "    ""issueTime"": 1535545801765," & vbCrLf & "    ""price"": 4.5E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""quantity"": 2289.92000001," & vbCrLf & "    ""remainingQuantity"": 0.0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionByTrade"": 0.00018916," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusByTrade"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusRate"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionRate"": 0.0018," & vbCrLf & "    ""lastModificationTime"": 1535545801765" & vbCrLf & "  }," & vbCrLf & "  {" & vbCrLf & "    ""id"": 17637532551," & vbCrLf & "    ""currencyPair"": ""ORME/BTC""," & vbCrLf & "    ""goodUntilTime"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""type"": ""LIMIT_SELL""," & vbCrLf & "    ""orderStatus"": ""PARTIALLY_FILLED_AND_CANCELLED""," & vbCrLf & "    ""issueTime"": 1535545474694," & vbCrLf & "    ""price"": 4.78E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""quantity"": 2487.1," & vbCrLf & "    ""remainingQuantity"": 2289.92000001," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionByTrade"": 1.697E-05," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusByTrade"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""bonusRate"": 0," & vbCrLf & "    ""commissionRate"": 0.0018," & vbCrLf & "    ""lastModificationTime"": 1535545515636" & vbCrLf & "  }" & vbCrLf & "]"

And that sucks and hard to read. If a string contains a json, I want to see the json as it actually is. I want to be able to copy that to notepad.

How do I do so?

Comment: I think, if you just put your mouse over the value a menu will show up and there you will see magnifying lens. You just click there and you will see your JSON in perfect shape. And why do we need to see this long string?

Comment: Please turn that into an answer? I just want to show you how ugly things look.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do when debugging.

1. put mouse over your variable. Popup menu will show up and there you will see magnifying lens

[image]

- click that
  [image]

  2. Right-click on your variable, select "Quick Watch" in the menu a screen will show

[image]

click magnifying lens